# How to Read with Message Body C# when Service Bus Explorer Adds junk http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization when resubmitting messages -

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I'm working on a system built on Azure Service Bus and Azure Functions.

Our service bus messages are text based, usually json and we have started seeing errors in some of our messages about invalid characters in the text.

This doesn't affect all messages on the queue and I've been able to trace it back to using Service Bus Explorer to resubmit Dead Letter Queue messages with a Body type of "String"
[image: Resubmit Dialog]

In service bus explorer the message appears perfectly normal:
[image: Expected message is SBE]

however when reading the message from code the body text is:

***@06string083http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/�15Hi mate, how are you?***

I would like to be able to handle messages which have been submitted this way, but none of the messages on the ReceivedMessage Class work.  I've tried a number of approaches using C# in Linqpad

```
var client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);


var receiver = client.CreateReceiver(queueName, new ServiceBusReceiverOptions { ReceiveMode = ServiceBusReceiveMode.PeekLock});

string txtBody;
"Peek Messages".Dump();
var message = await receiver.PeekMessageAsync();
while (message != null)
{

    Stream stream = message.Body.ToStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream,Encoding.UTF8);
    txtBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
    txtBody.Dump("Read with stream");
    
    txtBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body.ToArray());
    txtBody.Dump("Read with Byte[]");
    
    message.Body.ToString().Dump("Read with toString");
    
    message = await receiver.PeekMessageAsync();
}
```

This only happens if the message was resubmitted as a string - resubmitting as stream works as expected.

It seems to me like there should be a way of detecting this type of message and an alternate way of reading it.  Service bus Explorer is clearly handling it somehow.

Comment: You can take a look at the source code for Service Bus Explorer :). I ran into the exact same issue some time back and when I looked at the code, I found that it tries multiple ways to deserialize a message.

Comment: I've looked and cannot see any special handling also not entirely sure where to look. I can see that SBE is using BrokeredMessagaes which are not supported in Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus - it has ReceivedMessage instead.

Comment: The stream should work as then the data is sent as a byte array that is not serialized.

Comment: Also, the tool is undergoing some changes and eventually would be migrated to the latest, 3rd ASB SDK. Being a very old tool with way too many features, it will take time (and some feature pruning). You're always welcome to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm adding my own answer to help others.

Jesse Squire pointed my in the right direction to the service bus interop samples however that approach only works where the message has been serialized and contains the "serialization junk".

The vast majority of messages coming through my queues are generated with new libraries and are "clean". It's only a small portion of messages which have been "repaired and resubmitted" from the DQL using Service Bus Explorer or other tools based on older libraries that cause a problem.

I solved this by checking for serialization markers in the text as shown below.

```
string ReadMessageText(ServiceBusReceivedMessage message)
{
    string msgText = message.Body.ToString();

    if (msgText.StartsWith("@") && msgText.Contains(@"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization"))
    {
        var deserializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(string));
        XmlDictionaryReader reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateBinaryReader(message.Body.ToStream(), XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max);

        // deserialize the XML envelope into a string
        msgText = (string)deserializer.ReadObject(reader);
    }
    return msgText.Trim();
}
```

This requires System.Runtime.Serialization for the DataContractSerializer and System.Xml for the reader.

Answer (score 2):

Service Bus Explorer is based on a legacy SDK which uses a `DataContractSerializer` to encode the message payload.  This approach was deprecated and not carried forward into the newer SDKs.

`Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` makes no assumptions about how your message payload was serialized or encoded, returning only the raw bytes.  To interact with a payload from Service Bus Explorer, you'll need to use an equivalent serializer to transform the payload.

An example of doing so can be found in the [Service Bus Interop sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/samples/Sample08_Interop.md#receiving-a-message-using-azuremessagingservice-that-was-sent-with-windowsazureservicebus).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jesse that sample does a great job of reading the messages that have the "serialization junk" but it throws an exception when trying to read the majority of messages on the queue which don't have a prefix.  Is there something nicer than checking the body text for the leading '@' to decide how to handle the text?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of; the SDK intentionally treats the body as opaque and makes no assumptions about its format or content.  The responsibility lies with the publisher and consumer to agree on the format for exchange.    Normally, we advise adding an application property with a serialization hint or setting the `ContentType` when publishing to provide context to consumers where the format may not be clear for consumers.